# How do I deal with excessive CLOSE_WAIT which are clogging up Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr5

I'm running Solr 5.1 in SolrCloud mode, and indexing a lot of documents. It runs fine for a while, but then I'm unable to connect via the HTTP interface.

An excessive number of TCP connections appear to be open. I put a Nginx reverse proxy in front of Solr. Nginx reports has about 300 open connections, but solr has about 29,000. It appears even when Nginx closes the connection, Solr keeps it open.

In the Solr logs I repeatedly see the following:

> Unable to write response, client closed connection or we are shutting down
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:914)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.flush(AbstractGenerator.java:443)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$Output.flush(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1094)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.solr.util.FastWriter.flush(FastWriter.java:137)
>       at org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriterUtil.writeQueryResponse(QueryResponseWriterUtil.java:54)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.writeResponse(SolrDispatchFilter.java:815)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:455)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:220)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.writeTo(ByteArrayBuffer.java:375)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:164)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.flush(StreamEndPoint.java:194)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:838)
>       ... 36 more

How do I fix Solr? Do I need to tweak Jetty settings.

Comment: Are your SolrCloud requests route via nginx proxy? That would seem unnecessary and - possibly - unexpected. The actual CLOSE_WAIT is not Solr issue, but an O/S issue. You could look at reducing it's length for your O/S.

Comment: How are you indexing items into Solr? I would suggest to check your client to make sure it is not starting a new socket for each transmission, I ran into this before when indexing with a lot of threads.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was immediately committing every transaction. When I changed it to only commit every 10 minutes, it solved the issue.